# Why is my file not getting overwritten from the start in Python and why can't I read entire lines?

Tags: python, file

So, I have a program which gets a first random number and then two other numbers stored in file, in the form of two variables. My problems start from the moment I try to get the variables from the file.

```
import random
tries = random.randint(0, 20)
output = open("Results", "r+")
average = int(output.readline(1))
coef = int(output.readline(2))
first_line = (average * coef + tries)
first_line = str(first_line)
second_line = coef + 1
second_line = str(second_line)
output_text = first_line + "\n" + second_line
output.write(output_text)
output.close()
```

I already have a Results file with previous results which looks like :

```
11
1
```

After running the program once and getting tries = 13, the Results file looks like that :

```
11
114
2
```

Where I would like to have :

```
24
2
```

I think that the problem comes partially from the fact that when I try to read the past results, turns out that average = 1 and coef = 1 where average is suppose to be equal to 11. And that the other part comes from the moment when I try to write them back onto my file.

P.S. : I am using Python 3.9.6 and Spyder from the Anaconda distribution.
P.S.S. : What's wrong with my post ? I just want to know the reason to make my future posts better.

Comment: So you want `output = open("Results", "r")` instead of using "r+"?

Comment: @Ghoti No, because I want to write my results back onto the file.

Comment: You probably want to learn the seek() function.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for your answer, I can't use this solution as it would require me to know the position of the second line which is dependant from the length of the first line which migth change as the number will get bigger.

Comment: Can't you just seek to the beginning of the file and write both lines?

Comment: @ThePhoton I could use that but then how do I read the second line? Thanks for answering!

Comment: Your example shows reading two lines, then writing two lines. Just do that, but seek back to position 0 in between.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks, to @ThePhoton and some googling I managed to get it all working so this is my new code:

```
import random
tries = random.randint(0, 20)
output = open("Results", "r")
somme = int(output.readline())
coef = int(output.readline())
output.close()
output = open("Results", "w")
first_line = somme + tries
second_line = coef + 1
first_line = str(first_line)
second_line = str(second_line)
output_text = [first_line, "\n", second_line]
output.writelines(output_text)
output.close()
```